# surname is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Character model. I'm trying to save a new one using Django Rest Framework.

My view:

```
def create_character(request):
    existing_character = Character.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if existing_character.count() > 0:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    request.GET = request.GET.copy()
    request.GET["user"] = request.user.id
    serializer = CharacterSerializer(data=request.GET)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse(status=401, content=serializer.errors)

    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

My model:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateField()
    age = models.SmallIntegerField()
    health = models.SmallIntegerField()
    happiness = models.SmallIntegerField()
    depression = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

my serializer:

```
class CharacterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    health = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    happiness = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    depression = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    date_created = serializers.DateField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Character
        fields = ('user', 'pk', 'name', 'surname', 'date_created', 'user', 'age', 'health', 'happiness', 'depression',
                  'date_created')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data["health"] = 100
        validated_data["happiness"] = 100
        validated_data["depression"] = 0
        validated_data["date_created"] = date.today()
        return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

when serializer calls the `return User.objects.create(**validated_data)` i'm gettine exception:

> 'surname' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CharacterSerializer, but for some reason you've told it to create a User not a Character.

Comment: Well, sometimes another pair of eyes helps a lot. Thanks :)